# What is the integral of $\sqrt{\cos2x}$with respect to $x$?

Tags: integration

What  is the integral of this trigonometric function with rational exponent $\sqrt{\cos2x}$ with respect to $x$? I have tried substitution taking $\sqrt{\cos2x}=t$. Later on I tried putting $2x=\arccos(t^2)$, but still I did not find any sinless solution.

Comment: You get an elliptic integral of the second kind.

Comment: OP asked a non-trivial question and presented their thoughts on the problem. Does not formatting with Mathjax warrant down votes? Why are people becoming so idealistic here?

Comment: If you know the answer then post it don't waste your time by putting such comments

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{I}=\int\sqrt{\cos(2x)}\space\text{d}x=\int\sqrt{2\cos^2(x)-1}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\sqrt{2(1-\sin^2(x))-1}\space\text{d}x=\int\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{2})^2\sin^2(x)}\space\text{d}x$$

Let the elliptic modulus $k$ satisfy $0<k^2<1$. (This may also be written in terms of the parameter $m=k^2$ or modular angle $\alpha=\arcsin(k)$ The incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind is then defined as:

$$\text{E}(\phi,k)\equiv\int_0^\phi\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(\theta)}\space\text{d}\theta$$

Source(s): [Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html).

Comment: I am a class 12 student.... Can you please elaborate what is elliptical integral of second kind?

Comment: @VvvishennnVats I have set a link in my answer where you can look that up.

Answer (score 0):

$\int\sqrt{cos2x}dx = \int\sqrt{(1-tan^2x})cosxdx.$ Now you can put sinx as t. Differentiating, $cosxdx=dt.$ $tanx= \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}.$ Upon substituting the inegral boils down to $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}dt$ which is $ln(t + \sqrt{t^2 +1}) + c.$

Comment: Perhaps not quite so simple, as $\tan x = t/\sqrt{1-t^2}$

Comment: Can I do anything to correct this?

Comment: I don't think so. Looking around it seems that the integral can not be expressed through 'elementary' functions (but I have not seen any proof).